# d3.json Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js, xampp

I am tring to use a php script to generate a json string and import it into a D3 [force directed graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) script as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="urf-8"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("getneighborhood.php", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

getneighborhood.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_WARNING);
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","****");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $focusid = 5885;
    if (!isset($focusid)) { echo "no focusid"; die; }
    $links = array();
    $nodes = array();
    $result = $con->query("SELECT a.PersonID as ego, a.PersonID as source, b.PersonID as target FROM messagexperson a, messagexperson b WHERE a.PersonID = $focusid and a.PersonID <> b.PersonID AND a.MessageID = b.MessageID UNION SELECT a.PersonID as ego, b.PersonID as source, c.PersonID as target FROM messagexperson a, messagexperson b,messagexperson c WHERE a.PersonID = $focusid and a.PersonID <>  b.PersonID AND a.PersonID <> c.PersonID AND b.PersonID < c.PersonID AND a.MessageID = b.MessageID AND a.MessageID = c.MessageID AND b.MessageID = c.MessageID");
    $nodectr = 0;   
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $from = $row[1];
        if (!isset($nodes[$from])) {
            $presult = $con->query("SELECT Name FROM person WHERE id = $from") or die(mysql_error());
            $temp = $presult->fetch_row();
            $nodes[$from]['name'] = $temp[0];
            $nodes[$from]['idx'] = $nodectr;
            $fromidx = $nodectr;
            $nodectr++;
        }
        else {
            $fromidx = $nodes[$from]['idx'];
        }
        $to = $row[2];
        if (!isset($nodes[$to])) {
            $presult = $con->query("SELECT Name FROM person WHERE id = $to") or die(mysql_error());
            $temp = $presult->fetch_row();
            $nodes[$to]['name'] = $temp[0];
            $nodes[$to]['idx'] = $nodectr;
            $toidx = $nodectr;
            $nodectr++;
        }
        else {
            $toidx = $nodes[$to]['idx'];
        }
        $data[$from][$to]++;
    }
    $nodectr = 0;
    foreach ($nodes as $id => $val) {
        $name = $val['name'];
        $d3['nodes'][$nodectr]['id'] = $name;
        $d3['nodes'][$nodectr]['group'] = 1;
        $nodectr++;
        $d3['nodes'];
    }
    $linkctr = 0;
    foreach ($data as $from => $list){
        $fromname = $nodes[$from]['name'];
        foreach ($list as $to => $count) {
            $toname = $nodes[$to]['name'];
            $d3['links'][$linkctr]['source'] = $fromname;
            $d3['links'][$linkctr]['target'] = $toname;
            $d3['links'][$linkctr]['value'] = 1;
            $linkctr++;
        }
    }    
    echo json_encode($d3);
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

When I run this, I get in the console (same for Chrome and Firefox):

```
mailgraph.htm:32 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2519
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.v4.min.js:7)
```

The offending line is "if (error) throw error", and poition 2519 is the second to last character of the json string.

When I save the output of getneighborhood.php as a JSON file and use that in the d3.json function instead, the script runs fine and produces the expected output.  Have searched around and found some advice to specify UTF-8 encoding for the html and .js, which as you can see I did, but that didn't fix the problem.  The PHP script is running on XAMPP, if that is important.

Any ideas about what the problem could be?

Comment: Your error is at `json.parse()` in ***mailgraph.htm***. And none of the code you've put up has either keyword!?

Comment: Your code is sending HTML in some way to the js. that's why it complains about `<`

Comment: @AP. `d3.json("getneighborhood.php"` d3 is calling the json.parse

Comment: @Steve paste the output of what you get when you navigate to `getneighborhood.php`. Easy way to do that is by typing this into your web-console on the webpage `window.location = 'getneighborhood.php'`. Then right click and view source!

Comment: copy your json and go to http://jsonlint.com/ and check if your json is valid first to rule out if it's your code or the json.

Comment: @AP I did that and it was throwing an error "Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\bostock\getneighborhood.php on line 69".  Should have been mysqli_close($con) :-/  Thanks for the help!